# WHERE query when creating layer in MapServer

Tags: postgis, mapserver

Is there a way to have WHERE clause when you're querying for PostGIS data on MapScript? like, `geom FROM country WHERE country = 'usa' USING unique gid`.

My current workaround is by creating VIEW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MapServer, your PostGIS LAYER can contain a subquery. This is the recommended way to do it. Note that your subquery must return all fields you are using in your layer label, class, etc.

```
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
CONNECTION "dbname=yourdatabasename user=yourdbusername"
DATA "geom from (SELECT geom, attr1, attr2 FROM country WHERE country = 'usa') as subquery USING unique gid USING srid=4326"
```

[See the documentation](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/postgis.html#data-access-connection-method) for more details